# Ansible casting string to bool

Tags: linux, ansible, boolean

I am trying to ask the user if they would like the new user they are creating to be a sudor or not.

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      vars_prompt:
        - name: is_sudoer
          prompt: Is the new user a sudoer (Y/N)?
          private: no
      tasks:
        - name: debugTruth
          debug:
            msg: "Statement True"
          when: is_sudoer|default(false)|bool == true
        - name: debugFalse
          debug:
            msg: "Statement False"
          when: is_sudoer|default(false)|bool == false
```

However, no matter what I input, the script always defaults to false. I thought "y", "Y", "yes" etc always evaluated to true in the ansible.

Here is the output I get:

```
ansible-playbook manageUsers.yml

Is the new user a sudoer (Y/N)?: y
...    
    
TASK [debugTruth] **********************************************
skipping: [localhost]
    
TASK [debugFalse] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
  "msg": "Statement False"
    }
```

As you can see I always get a false response.

Comment: What if you input `True` ?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Y/N"` is not automatically converted to boolean in Ansible. Both `"Y"` and `"N"` are simply non-empty strings and will be evaluated as `True`. The solution is simple. Test the string, for example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: User is sudoer
      when: is_sudoer|lower == 'y'
```

For details about the "truthie/falsie" see below. Given the lists

```yaml
    list1:
      - true
      - yes
      - Y
      - y
      - x
    list2:
      - false
      - no
      - N
      - n
      - x
```

Test [truthy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-truthiness) of *list1*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is Truthy [{{ item is truthy }}]"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: True is Truthy [True]
  msg: True is Truthy [True]
  msg: Y is Truthy [True]
  msg: y is Truthy [True]
  msg: x is Truthy [True]
```

and *list2*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is Truthy [{{ item is truthy }}]"
      loop: "{{ list2 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: False is Truthy [False]
  msg: False is Truthy [False]
  msg: N is Truthy [True]
  msg: n is Truthy [True]
  msg: x is Truthy [True]
```

Test *falsy* of *list1*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is Falsy [{{ item is falsy }}]"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: True is Falsy [False]
  msg: True is Falsy [False]
  msg: Y is Falsy [False]
  msg: y is Falsy [False]
  msg: x is Falsy [False]
```

and *list2*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is Falsy [{{ item is falsy }}]"
      loop: "{{ list2 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: False is Falsy [True]
  msg: False is Falsy [True]
  msg: N is Falsy [False]
  msg: n is Falsy [False]
  msg: x is Falsy [False]
```

Comment: Have uploaded the code, but why is theuser still not sudo: /usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/jerry/.Xauthority does not exist

Comment: Make it [mre]. I've updated your question as a hint of what it means. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then see [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and delete your comment.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought "y","Y","yes" etc always evaluated to true in the ansible.

That statement is not correct, as you can see here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L76 values that resolve to boolean true by the filter are the strings "1", "on", "yes", and "true" (case insensitive), or the numeral 1 (so, *NOT* "y"):

```
if isinstance(a, string_types):
    a = a.lower()
if a in ('yes', 'on', '1', 'true', 1):
    return True
return False
```

Additionally, the more correct way to implement the conditionals as suggested in the comments by @P, is

```
- name: debugTruth
  debug:
    msg: "Statement True"
  when: is_sudoer | bool

- name: debugFalse
  debug:
    msg: "Statement False"
  when: not is_sudoer | bool
```

The `default(false)` is not needed because the empty string (ie. the user typing just the enter key at the (Y/N) prompt) will be False in the when. Finally, avoid the `==`.

Comment: Have uploaded the code, but why is theuser still not sudo: /usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/jerry/.Xauthority does not exist

Comment: If you use my code snippet in your user creation task, you'll see it will create the superuser. ~/.XAuthority stores authenticated open X sessions for the user and has nothing to do with sudoers. Your code (now edited away from the post), was not even adding the user to the sudoers, but just adding the newly created user account to the `root` group. To check it works, after creation, use `groups testuser` and you'll see it shows as `testuser : testuser root`